# It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console (zeromq v4.1.3)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, anaconda, spyder

Anaconda3-2.4.0-Windows-x86_64 install including Python 3.5 64-bit and Spyder 2.3.7.

Windows 7 Professional, SP1, 64 bit.

I am trying to follow a series of videos on youtube to add a matplotlib graph to a tkinter window, the first 5 videos cover the initial creation of windows and buttons in the tkinter window which was all fairly simple. The problem occurs when i get to the first matplotlib addition. Even though i copy exactly what the guy in the video does within Python, i get an error where he gets a working program.

Here is a link to the video i am currently attempting to follow:

[How to add a Matplotlib Graph to Tkinter Window in Python 3 - Tkinter tutorial Python 3.4 p. 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw6M-BnAPP0&index=6&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk)

There is a list of the other videos in the series to the right when playing.

The error message given within the ipython console is: "It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console". The message repeats every few seconds untill 'restart kernel' is selected.

In the code below if it is run as is, no windows are opened. If 'canvas.show()' is commented out, a window opens and a python crash error is shown in Windows.

the program runs and the buttons all function correctly if 'canvas.show()', 'canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)' and 'canvas._tkcanvas.pack()' are all commented out.

I have researched this and found the zeromq issue with versions 4.0.6 and 4.1.1 which were fixed in the newer versions. Using the 'conda list' command in the anaconda prompt shows the version number 4.1.3, therefore i do not believe this to be the issue.

I am running in python 3.5 where 'sentdex' (the guy in the video) is running 3.4, could this cause the issue?

Here is my code (minus 3 classes which open windows with buttons on):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("Arial, 12")

class Home(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="icon1.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Converters & Calculators")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, MPL_Tutorial):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Please select a calculator or convertor from  the list:", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

        MPL_Tutorial_button = ttk.Button(self, text = "Graph Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MPL_Tutorial))
        MPL_Tutorial_button.pack()

class MPL_Tutorial(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

        Home_button = ttk.Button(self, text = "Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        Home_button.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize = (5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [5,8,1,3,7,4,9,5])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack()


app = Home()
app.mainloop()
```

I have edited some of the content while writing the program to reflect the application i eventually want the program for, a calculator / converter for various engineering bits and pieces, such as 'reflection coefficient / VSWR ratio / Return loss conversion'. I believe the only things i have edited are names of things and some padding values.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I fully expect the answer to be something i have done wrong, i am fairly new to programming as a whole.

Edit: Removed sections of code which referred to the other code i left out as this would undoubtedly cause 'extra' issues if anyone tried to run it.

Comment: I think this is fixed by updating to Matplotlib 1.5. You can do that by opening a terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe`) and running this command: `conda update matplotlib`

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you for your comment. It seems i do not have the necessary permissions to update packages. Ill work on this and let you know if it fixes my issue.

Comment: Also I cannot install the .whl file using pip.

Comment: We're going to release Anaconda 2.4.1 this week, which will include Matplotlib 1.5, in case that helps :-)

Comment: Perfect, I shall keep an eye out for it. Thank you very much!